# Encoding problem (Hebrew UTF8) in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, encoding, hebrew

I have a blog (of a friend) I am failing to fix:

```
http://www.nivcalderon.com/
```

The language of the website is Hebrew, but the encoding scrambles the output, and I can't find how to fix it.

I tried changing the DB colliation to be utf8_general_ci.

I added this:

```
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
```

To the wp-config
(and also this: define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
But removed it later, since it didn't seem to fix the problem)

Any ideas of what else to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is causing because of a bad import, which make the database to contain double-encoded utf-8 strings. It can be fixed by exporting the tables as latin1 and than importing it as UTF-8. This is not a WordPress fault.